# Sharing sets of fields among content types?

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I know it's possible (and often recommended) to re-use fields across multiple content types, if those fields do indeed do the same thing.

I'm wondering if it's possible to re-use "sets" of fields: say you have 10 content types, all of which use the same 8 fields at the beginning (eg. title, description, cover image, author...), and then go on to each have their own fields afterwards. It would make sense to be able to say "fields A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H are re-used in the same order in content types 1 through 10", and only have to specify their characteristics in one spot, instead of adding each field (even if it's a shared field) to each content type separately.

I imagine this is possible with a field collection, but this doesn't seem to be the best solution:

- the fields aren't semantically linked to each other other than being common to all node types
- problems could arise if one of the shared fields is a field collection itself

Is there another solution to this?

Comment: Content types don't support the concept of inheritance, I think that's basically what you're asking? If so, the closest you'll get is something like [Bundle Copy](https://drupal.org/project/bundle_copy)

Comment: @Clive I'm not sure, really (Drupal newbie ;)) by inheritance do you mean that I can't have a content type (with the shared fields in it) that is included in other content types, yes? (Bundle Copy looks like it's a one-time thing, only upon content type creation... but yes, it would probably solve most of the problem)

Comment: Similar to inheritance in OO programming is what I meant, sounds like we're on the same page - Drupal doesn't have any mechanisms to automagically sync fields from say a 'parent' or 'base' content type down to 'child' or 'derivative' content types, it's very much a manual process (hence Bundle Copy). Maybe there are other solutions now though, I haven't checked in with this stuff for a while

Comment: @Clive Right, thanks - this at least points me in one possible direction :)

Comment: There are a few modules for cross-domain syncing that might be adaptable - you could use Rules, with or without Bundle Copy to create a pseudo-sync system as well.